# Two competing scroll to anchor functions in same one page html page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Both functions work independently, but I'm not sure why they won't work together. Currently, whichever function comes second in the code is the dominant function that will run while the other is disabled.

```
  function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top-135},'slow');
  }

  $("a").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
    scrollToAnchor(href);
});
```

and the second script:

```
function openProject(href) {
    //remove existing content
    if ($("#contentBox").is(":visible")) {
        $("#contentBox").animate({
            height: "0"
        }).empty();
    }
    $("#contentBox").load("projects.html " + href, function () {
        //create map
        var mapLat = $(this).find(".map-canvas .lat").text();
        var mapLon = $(this).find(".map-canvas .lon").text();
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(mapLat, mapLon),
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoom: 16
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map($(this).find(".map-canvas")[0], mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(mapLat, mapLon),
            map: map
        });
        //create slideshow
        var slides = $(this).find(".flexslider");
        if (slides.length) {
            slides.flexslider();
        }
        //open
        var contentBoxHeight = $(this).css("height", "950px").height();
        $(this).css("height", "0");
        $("#contentBox").animate({
            height: contentBoxHeight
        });
        var headerHeight = 135;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - headerHeight
        });

        $(".close").on("click", function (e) {
            $("#contentBox").empty();
            $("#contentBox").animate({
                height: 0
            });
        });
    });
}
});
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are running into? Be more specific. What is the behavior you are getting?

Comment: In the case shown, the second <script> runs correctly (links that load HTML into a DIV on the page), while the scroll animation of the first <script> do not function. It goes to the anchor tag but it does not animate the scroll. If I reverse the order of the scripts on the page, then the scrolling animation will work while the links that load HTML into a DIV do not.

Comment: Example of scrolling working while projects won't load: http://www.addinc.com/dev/brg/index.html

Comment: Example of the reversed script order on page (go to properties and click a box in the grid to load html into DIV): http://www.addinc.com/dev/brg/index_scriptReversed.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. The second link tag needed a class so that the functions weren't overwriting each other. Changed "a" to "a.linkNav"

```
<!-- Scroll to Anchor -->
<script> 
 function scrollToAnchor(aid){
   var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top-135},'slow');
 }

  $("a.linkNav").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
    scrollToAnchor(href);
});  
</script>
```